# Color panel in the properties section is changed

Tags: color

I was using blender and might've accidently pressed some keys and so when I go to my section to add color it is not at the original perspective that I want it to be. I need this back because it gives me like 3 options for color and none of them add nodes to my node editor. please help.

How do I change it from this perspective

[image]

Back to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally change to Blender render instead of Cycles? At the top bar in the 3D editor try switching it to Cycles Render. Hope that helps :).

Comment: @Nicksin on't post thanks. Upvote the question, or consider marking it as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Np but please mark the question as answered as mentioned by Mr. Ramos. Good luck with your work in Blender!